# How to make a multiple trace plot as a reusable code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I somehow tried to make the  reusable code of plots for eg a bar_graph as:

```
def bar(x,y,text,marker,orientation,name):
    barchart=[go.Bar(x=x,y=y,text=text,marker=marker,orientation=orientation,name=name)]
    ........
```

In a similar way how can I make a reusable code for multiple traces ?

for this below code,

```
fig = go.Figure()

# Add Traces

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.index),
               y=list(df.High),
               name="High",
               line=dict(color="#33CFA5")))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.index),
               y=[df.High.mean()] * len(df.index),
               name="High Average",
               visible=False,
               line=dict(color="#33CFA5", dash="dash")))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.index),
               y=list(df.Low),
               name="Low",
               line=dict(color="#F06A6A")))fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        go.layout.Updatemenu(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="None",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False, True, False]},
                           {"title": "Yahoo",
                            "annotations": []}]),
                dict(label="High",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, False, False]},
                           {"title": "Yahoo High",
                            "annotations": high_annotations}]),
                dict(label="Low",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, False, True, True]},
                           {"title": "Yahoo Low",
                            "annotations": low_annotations}]),

            ]),
        )
    ])

# Set title
fig.update_layout(title_text="Yahoo")

fig.show()
```

here, the traces would be of any,i.e., based on combination of values passed for each trace, so how can I make it as a reusable code?

.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily loop through the columns of your dataframe and create a trace for each of them like in the snippet below.

```
# crate traces
traces={}
for col in df.columns:
    traces['trace_' + col]=go.Bar(x=df.index, name=col, y=df[col])

# convert data to form required by plotly
data=list(traces.values())

# build figure
fig=go.Figure(data)
fig.show()
```

---

#### Edited suggestion after conversations with OP in comments and chat.

Without a reproducible data sample, it's a bit hard to suggest a perfect solution. But here's a suggestion that is reusable in the sense that:

**(1):** it's flexible with regards to the number of columns in your source dataframe and uses a for loop to add traces as requested,

**(2):** it calculates max() and min() for each column,

**(3):** it is structured as a function and can easiliy be applied to any dataframe.

I've put together some sample data that looks like this:

[image]

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 1:**

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# data
humid = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(low=25, high=40, size=6).tolist())
windy = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(low=40, high=60, size=6).tolist())
df = pd.concat([humid,windy], axis = 1)
df.columns=['Humidity', 'windspeed']
df.index = ['Shanghai', 'Houston', 'Venice', 'Munich', 'Milan', 'Turin']


def plotMaxMin(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        #print(df[col].max())
        df[col+'_max']=df[col].max()
        df[col+'_min']=df[col].min()

    # crate traces
    traces={}
    for col in df.columns:
        traces['trace_' + col]=go.Scatter(x=df.index, name=col, y=df[col])

    # convert data to form required by plotly
    data=list(traces.values())

    # build figure
    fig=go.Figure(data)
    fig.show()

plotMaxMin(df=df)
```

#### Test for reusability using an edited dataframe:

**Plot 2:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
df2=df.copy(deep=True)
df2['Temperature']=pd.Series(np.random.uniform(low=-5, high=40, size=6).tolist())

plotMaxMin(df2)
```

We're sill missing the `updatemnu()`. As it is, the plot still is pretty interactive by only clicking the names of the series.

#### Test with go.layout.Updatemenu()

This will take some more tweaking to make perfect, but the main functioanlities seem to be in place, so I hope you'll be able to add a few things to get it exaclty like you want with your dataset.

**Plot 3:**

[image]

**Code 3:**

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# data
humid = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(low=25, high=40, size=6).tolist())
windy = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(low=40, high=60, size=6).tolist())
df = pd.concat([humid,windy], axis = 1)
df.columns=['Humidity', 'windspeed']
df.index = ['Shanghai', 'Houston', 'Venice', 'Munich', 'Milan', 'Turin']


def plotMaxMin(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        #print(df[col].max())
        df[col+'_max']=df[col].max()
        df[col+'_min']=df[col].min()

    # crate traces
    traces={}
    for col in df.columns:
        traces['trace_' + col]=go.Scatter(x=df.index, name=col, y=df[col])

    # convert data to form required by plotly
    data=list(traces.values())

    # build figure
    fig=go.Figure(data)

    # add dropdown functionality

    fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        go.layout.Updatemenu(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="None",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False, True, False]},
                           {"title": "Yahoo",
                            "annotations": []}]),
                dict(label="High",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, False, False]},
                           {"title": "Yahoo High",
                            "annotations": high_annotations}]),
                dict(label="Low",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, False, True, True]},
                           {"title": "Yahoo Low",
                            "annotations": high_annotations}]),

            ]),
        )
    ])



    fig.show()

plotMaxMin(df=df)
```

#### Edit 2: Example on how to expand function with more arguments to customize your plotly figure

**Plot 4:**

[image]

**Code 4:**

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# data
humid = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(low=25, high=40, size=6).tolist())
windy = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(low=40, high=60, size=6).tolist())
df = pd.concat([humid,windy], axis = 1)
df.columns=['Humidity', 'Windspeed']
df.index = ['Shanghai', 'Houston', 'Venice', 'Munich', 'Milan', 'Turin']


def plotMaxMin(df, colors):
    """Adds max and min for all df columns and plots the data using plotly

    Arguments:
    ==========
    df - pandas dataframe
    colors - dictionary with single word to identify line category and assign color

    Example call:
    =============
    plotMaxMin(df=df, colors={'wind':'#33CFA5', 'humidity':'#F06A6A'})

    """


    # add max and min for each input column
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col+'_max']=df[col].max()
        df[col+'_min']=df[col].min()

    # sort df columns by name
    df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)

    # crate traces
    traces={}
    for col in df.columns:

        # format traces
        if 'Humid' in col:
            linecolor = colors['humidity']

        if 'Wind' in col:
            linecolor = colors['wind']

        traces['trace_' + col]=go.Scatter(x=df.index, name=col, y=df[col], line=dict(color=linecolor))

    # convert data to form required by plotly
    data=list(traces.values())

    # build figure
    fig=go.Figure(data)

    # uncomment bloew section to add dropdown functionality

    #fig.update_layout(
    #updatemenus=[
    #    go.layout.Updatemenu(
    #        active=0,
    #        buttons=list([
    #            dict(label="None",
    #                 method="update",
    #                 args=[{"visible": [True, False, True, False]},
    #                       {"title": "Yahoo",
    #                        "annotations": []}]),
    #            dict(label="High",
    #                 method="update",
    #                 args=[{"visible": [True, True, False, False]},
    #                       {"title": "Yahoo High",
    #                        "annotations": high_annotations}]),
    #            dict(label="Low",
    #                 method="update",
    #                 args=[{"visible": [False, False, True, True]},
    #                       {"title": "Yahoo Low",
    #                        "annotations": high_annotations}]),
    #        ]),
    #    )
    #])



    fig.show()

plotMaxMin(df=df, colors={'wind':'#33CFA5', 'humidity':'#F06A6A'})
```

Comment: here, `X` can have values of a column of dataframe also right? for eg: x=df[col]

Comment: @Codenewbie Sure! But how you do it will depend a bit on what you're trying to show. Take a look at the answers to Plotly: How to make stacked bar chart from single trace?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240033/plotly-how-to-make-stacked-bar-chart-from-single-trace/55260429#55260429

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is a reusable generic code for the add_trace , for this i need to have number of traces based on combination of values (parameters) sent, 1)How can I pass multiple combinations of parameters(x,y,......)2) for no. of combinations sent I need to add that many traces dynamically....

Comment: Not actually a stacked bar but multiple traces with drop down as here:https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/  which I want to have a dynamic function

Comment: also as per your code, if suppose i have a df with columns a,b,c and one trace i want to be of x=a ,y=b and other as x=a,y=c ? how this is achieved mate?

Comment: @Codenewbie If you find the time to provide a reproducible data-sample, I'll happily have a look at the specifics.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you, you mean a sample data to provide or any thing else?

Comment: You've got a dataframe with columns such as `High`, `High averge` etc. It's a bit hard to discern what are columns from the same dataframe and what's possible calculated values. If you provide a small sample from your datasource, anyone interested can provide an answer more easily for example by copying the data directly from the question using `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')`. You can take a look at one of my own questions and see one way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155925/weekday-as-factor-variable-in-a-linear-regression-model-using-statsmodels

Comment: @Codenewbie How's the sample data coming along? In fact, even a screenshot of your df would be helpful.

Comment: If the sample df have columns as::  A,B,C,D,.... and I want the traces for 1) A vs B 2) B and C 3) A and B as above so how can I pass them as arguments to a function say add_trace( which take care of multiple traces to make it reusable)

Comment: @Codenewbie Remind me on monday. I'll see if I can look closer at it then.

Comment: sure sir...i will

Comment: @Codenewbie I invited you to a chat session.

Comment: hey I have joined it, sorry for late